# Error installing LaTeX package .def not found

Tags: latex

I have installed LaTeX from the Ubuntu repository, I want to use [this package](https://code.google.com/p/handlatex/) that isn't in the repositories. I followed [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaTeX). I downloaded the package to my home directory, then I went into the folder with `cd handlatex` I did `latex hand.ins` and

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/hand
sudo cp hand.sty /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/hand
```

but when trying to compile the .tex file it says

```
! LaTeX Error: File `hand.def' not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a [user install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaTeX#User_install) copying the files .sty and .def. Then run the file using the command line as it says in the documentation of the package. You have to type

```
handlatex foo.tex
```

Comment: Can you add more details to the answer please? It seems it's a useful answer